# ぞ is the short form of こそ?

Tags: expressions

Can ぞ be the short form of こそ?
Here below a sentence example:

> これぞあたしの本だ！！

[Here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9E) I found that これぞ = this (emphatic), but I'm curious to know if that *zo* came from *koso* or not. Thk U in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ぞ is an archaic Japanese particle which works similarly to こそ in modern Japanese. In modern Japanese, これぞ is not common any more, but `これぞＸ（だ）！` is sometimes used like a catchphrase:

> - これぞラーメン！ "*This* is (true) ramen!"
> - これぞアメリカだ！ "*This* is America!"

Besides, これぞ is occasionally used to simulate old-fashioned, pompous and/or [chūnibyo-like](https://bangin.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/%E4%B8%AD%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85chunibyo/) way of speaking, mainly in fiction. 「これぞあたしの本だ！！」 is not incorrect, but sounds a little funny because the これぞ part is unnaturally archaic.

Something like this would be fine in a fantasy work (imagine an old wizard with long beard saying this):

> これぞ吾輩が長年探し求め[し](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14498/5010)魔道書！！

No one speak like this in reality, though.

Answer (score 5):

If ぞ and こそ are etymologically related to one another, it will have been a long time ago. Both particles have a long history in the Japanese language and were used commonly in Classical Japanese. However, it seems more likely that こそ is derived from ぞ rather than the other way around.

In Classical Japanese, the two particles actually functioned differently on a grammatical level - Classical Japanese had a feature called 係り{かかり}結び{むすび}, in which certain particles caused the following verb to take a different form, and the forms used were different for ぞ (which used the 連用形{れんようけい}) and こそ (which used the 已然形{いぜんけい}). So they were clearly quite distinct particles as long ago as Classical Japanese.

That said, ぞ was apparently pronounced as そ earlier in the language's history (the [Wikipedia article for 係り結び](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%82%E3%82%8A%E7%B5%90%E3%81%B3) mentions that it was そ in the 上代{じょうだい} period), so it's not unlikely that the two words are related if you go back far enough. The [Wiktionary entry for the classical こそ](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D) mentions that one theory is that こそ comes from ぞ combined with the classical pronoun こ, which would make こそ originally equivalent to the whole expression これぞ itself!