# What does し of されし means？

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjugations, auxiliary-き

I was playing hollow knight and a character said "愛されし王のために", i searched and found out that し is a conjugation of an aulixiary that means past and it was used in classical japanese, but i asked a japanese friend about it and he said that it means 愛されている王のために, and し is an old way to say ている, which one is right？or しhas this two meanings？

Comment: [Related?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65590/is-選ばれし者-a-grammatically-correct-translation-of-the-chosen-one?rq=1) If 選ばれしもの means the same as 選ばれている者, just more classical (like someone says thou art instead of you are in English), then 愛されし王 should just be a more classical and literary form of 愛されている王.

Answer (score 3):

Theし is indeed 連体形 (pre-noun form) of the auxiliary き, meaning past.  The phrase means 愛され**た**王のために in modern version, which is literally *the king who was loved* or *the loved king*, the latter of which in turn can be translated as 愛されている王.

So grammatically you are correct. 愛された or 愛されている is a matter of translation. 愛された sounds like the king is dead or the fact of being loved is past (like *the king who used to be loved*.

Cf. [「き・けり」](https://www.kotenbunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%8D-%E3%81%91%E3%82%8A/)